# RDBに保存された画像データから類似画像を検索する方法

Tags: mysql, 機械学習

RDBに画像から抽出した特徴ベクトルと画像のパスを保存しています。
指定の画像と類似した画像を検索したいのですがselectで絞り込む方法がわかりません。
手動でタグ付けして絞り込むしかないんでしょうか？

Comment: よい質問と回答にするため、少し教えていただきたいことがあります。

対象のRDBには、どのような形で、どのような画像の特徴ベクトルを入力していますか？
たとえばカラム単位で1次元ずつ(長さx高さ)次元分の列を持つ形で、そのサイズに縮小した画像の画素を全て持っている、など。
テーブルのスキーマ構造を書いていただけると嬉しいです。

もう1つは、どういった意味で"類似している画像である"と考えたいですか？
ヒストグラムとして、大まかに色がにていることを類似すると言うかもしれません。
同じ物体が写っている画像なら、それが類似していると言いたいのかもしれません。

このあたりについてもう少し具体的な質問だと、大変答えやすくなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

keras_vggfaceで抽出した特徴データになります。
1カラム(text)に抽出した配列のjsonを保存してあります。
類似度はコサイン類似度で求めた結果で判断しています。

Comment: 画像は人の顔の画像になります。
elasticsearchで出来そうなので？そちらで対応することにしました